# Is it possible to find cardinality of set of series product?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z_{k}$, $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}v_{k}$ be complex series and $W = \{z_{k},v_{\ell}\}^{\infty, \infty}_{k,\ell=0}$ - set of all possible products of $z_{k}, v_{\ell}$

Let enumerate $W = \{w_{i}\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ in any order you want and then make a series 
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}w_{i}
$$
Every single series above we call product of series. Notice, that any two products differ by permutation of members.

> Question: Is it possible to find the cardinality of set of products?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Steinitz's_theorem